# Extend interface in mongoose schema to add plugin method

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I have a Schema Model with a custom Interface:

```
interface IPost extends Document {
    created: Date;
    mensaje: string;
    img: string[];
    coords: string;
    usuario: string;
    test: string;
}
```

I use this interface when exporting model:

```
export const Post = model<IPost>('Post', postSchema);
```

I would like to use mongoose-paginate-v2 plugin, I initialized:

```
postSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
```

And if I export **Post Model** without my **IPost interface** I can `.paginate()` in my route, but not with my IPost interface.
I tried adding the method to my interface, trying to extend from mongoose-paginate-v2 types but i haven`t got it.

How can I add `.paginate()` method from mongoose-paginate-v2 to my interface? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend it for your self

```
interface IPpaginator {
        paginate(): void;

}

interface IPost extends Document, IPpaginator {
    created: Date;
    mensaje: string;
    img: string[];
    coords: string;
    usuario: string;
    test: string;
}
```

**Updates**

```
// import dependencies 
import { Document, Schema, Model, model} from "mongoose";

//export like a boss
export const Post: Model<IPost> = model<IPost>('Post', postSchema);
```

Comment: Getting same error, I don't know If I explained myself wrong. I want that when I import Post model in my route can do Post.paginate(). Now is throwing an error saying 'paginate' no exists in the type 'Model<Ipost, {}>.

Comment: Same error. I think I have to create a static method not instance method but I don't how cause the plugin already creates that method but not working when having my custom interface.

Answer (score 0):

I too am very new to typescript, thus won't be able to explain the whole code but here's the solution.

/* postModel.ts */

```
import { Schema, model, PaginateModel } from 'mongoose';

interface IPost extends Document {
    created: Date;
    mensaje: string;
    img: string[];
    coords: string;
    usuario: string;
    test: string;
}

const postSchema = new Schema({
    created: Date.now(),
    mensaje: String,
    img: [String],
    coords: String,
    test: String,
})

export default model<IPost, MongooseModel<IPost>>('Post', postSchema);
```

importing above file as:

```
import postModel from './postModel.ts'

postModel.paginate(filters, options)
```

You'll be able to use paginate function now.

Edit:
Do not forget to add mongoose-paginate-v2.
I personally like to add it while establishing a connection with the database. So that I don't have to import it in every schema that I create.

Here's how you can do the same:

```
// DEPENDENCIES
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import * as mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2';

const connection = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
  dbName: process.env.DB_NAME,
  authSource: 'admin',
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  pass: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  useNewUrlParser: !0,
  useUnifiedTopology: !0,
  useCreateIndex: !0,
  useFindAndModify: !1,
  autoIndex: !0,
})
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Mongoose connected to db');
  })
  .catch((err: Error) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Mongodb bridge connected');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err: Error) => {
  console.log(`Mongoose connection ERROR: ${err}`);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
  console.log('Mongoose connection disconnected');
});

process.on('SIGINT', async () => {
  await mongoose.connection.close();
  process.exit(0);
});

mongoose.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

export default connection;
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Apr 19, 2022, there is an example on the plugin GitHub site:
https://github.com/aravindnc/mongoose-paginate-v2#typescript

If anybody would like to gain a bit deeper understanding of extending mongoose when using TypeScript, I would also suggest reading this: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/statics-and-methods.html